# Fechamento de perguntas mal-elaboradas em inglês

Tags: debate, fechamento, razões-fechamento, perguntas-fechadas

Tenho visto uma coisa que por vezes me incomoda por aqui:

1. Usuário novato posta uma pergunta de péssima qualidade em inglês.
2. A pergunta é fechada por não estar em português.
3. O autor da pergunta traduz ela para o português e pede para reabrir.
4. Ninguém quer reabrir a pergunta porque ela é horrível por algum outro motivo (opinativa, ampla demais, fora do escopo, não é clara o suficiente, MCVE, duplicata, etc).
5. A pergunta fica com uma mensagem de fechamento dizendo que ela deveria ser traduzida para o português, embora já se encontre em português.
6. O autor da pergunta fica chateado e confuso por não entender porque não pode reabrir a pergunta vez que ele já a traduziu.

Assim sendo, acredito que a comunidade deveria abordar isso de uma forma diferente:

1. Se a pergunta puder ser fechada por mais do que um motivo, sendo o fato de estar em inglês apenas um deles, que se opte por fechá-la por um dos demais motivos (preferencialmente o mais grave, aquele que você escolheria se a pergunta estivesse traduzida).
2. Se a pergunta for relativamente simples/fácil de ser traduzida antes que votos de fechamento sejam dados, que algum dos nossos usuários mais experientes faça esse favor ao novato (mesmo que a pergunta claramente vá acabar sendo fechada depois por algum outro motivo).
3. Se a pergunta claramente for duplicata de uma outra, que se feche ela como duplicata mesmo se houver diversos outros problemas além de estar em inglês.
4. No caso de perguntas que tenham um inglês tão mal-escrito que chegue a ser ininteligível (ex: "*the fatal error please! ate me fix my string coidgo me all*"), que se feche como "*não está claro o suficiente*", vez que qualquer tentativa de traduzir isso por parte de alguém que não seja o autor da pergunta provavelmente seria inútil e arriscado e mesmo se o autor vier a traduzi-la, o resultado provavelmente vai continuar algo que não é claro o suficiente, ficando então o motivo de fechamento correto.

Em todos os casos, comentários na pergunta para apontar todos os problemas existentes e sugerir como o autor poderia saná-los são bem-vindos.

O que acham?

Comment: Acho excelente, totalmente de acordo.

Comment: "preferencialmente o mais grave" A gente tem alguma métrica objetiva de gravidade de motivos de fechamento? Algum ranking ou coisa assim?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Isso é subjetivo, e depende bastante da pergunta em questão. Mas na maioria das perguntas com sérios problemas, o problema mais grave é um tanto óbvio. Imagine como você iria fechar a pergunta se ela já estivesse em português.

Comment: Infelizmente nao posso colaborar com nenhuma das 4 opcoes, pois não sei inglês. Só me resta continuar votando fechamento por outro idioma e esperar que a comunidade ao menos crie mais consciência de que as filas não é parque de diversões e leve mais a serio as reaberturas.

Comment: Será que os outros sites cujo idioma não é inglês sofrem do mesmo problema? Talvez seja o caso de verificar (não sei como, talvez conversando com os respectivos moderadores), e se for o caso, tentar propor uma solução mais geral no [meta principal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), como poder indicar mais de um motivo de fechamento, ou algum outro mecanismo que deixe claro para o AP porque a pergunta não será reaberta, mesmo se for traduzida. Mas enquanto isso não muda, acho que as suas sugestões são válidas.

Comment: Acho que se a pergunta foi traduzida, mesmo que seja ruim (fora de escopo, duplicata, ampla, não clara etc) deveria ser reaberta e passar por um novo crivo de votação. Tb concordo que se alguém que saiba inglês possa traduzir antecipadamente para o AP, se não for uma coisa muito complexa.

Comment: @dvd O problema é que reabrir uma pergunta que claramente tem sérios problemas só para que ela seja fechada de novo não é produtivo. Além disso, para evitar abusos e manipulações, o sistema não permite que você vote para fechar a mesma pergunta duas vezes se não tiverem se passado pelo menos duas semanas entre um voto de fechamento e outro (ou alguma outra coisa parecida, não lembro ao certo os detalhes).

Comment: @VictorStafusa Ah sim, entendi.

Comment: Embora eu concorde com tudo o que foi dito, acho que ainda fica um ponto solto que é o dar a ideia de que se podem fazer perguntas em inglês aqui sem qualquer problema, uma vez que passarão a ser fechadas por outros motivos que não o facto de estar em inglês. Mas provavelmente esse será um mal bem menor que o que se passa atualmente.

Comment: @Isac Bem, se todas elas forem traduzidas (as que forem inteligíveis pelo menos) mesmo que sejam fechadas e os usuários deixarem comentários dizendo que a pergunta deve/deveria estar em português, não será passada tal impressão.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concordo 100%. Os pontos devem ser estes mesmo. Se alguém discorda favor colocar uma resposta mostrando porque isto seria ruim para a comunidade.

Comment: Eu debati esse assunto no chat a algum tempo, quando havia um staff ainda, sobre que talvez o fechamento por conta do idioma usado fosse uma má escolha, e que seria melhor traduzir de forma comunitária e procurar o fechamento adequado... O motivo que digo isto, na época 3 pessoas discutiram comigo e discordaram. Talvez eu não tenha usado as palavras mais claras, ou talvez realmente fosse algum desentendimento ou falta de compreensão do que poderia melhorar. Espero que essas pessoas venham apresentar pontos contra, só para ter certeza de todos pontos de vista.