# Qual a melhor opção para recomendar um fechamento?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Realizando algumas análises de publicação de baixo nível me deparei com essa resposta em inglês. Nesse caso, qual seria a opção mais apropriada para Recomendar a exclusão(se necessário)?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fechamento por estar em inglês só tem pra perguntas. Eu usaria "Não são necessários comentários", afinal realmente não precisa

Comment: Mas nesse caso não é um comentário de fato entende? Apesar de ser uma resposta bem formulada(*em alguns casos*), não deixa de ser uma resposta, ao meu ver não seria um comentário.

Comment: De forma análoga ao que foi discutido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108/112052), imagine que a resposta está em português. Se ela é ruim e deve ser removida, escolha a opção apropriada (pois se é uma resposta ruim que deve ser removida, a simples tradução não adiantaria nada, pois continuaria sendo uma resposta ruim). Mas caso a resposta esteja ok e não deva ser removida, coloque outro comentário (à parte, fora da fila de análise) dizendo para traduzir.