# Pergunta "não clara" e "não pode ser reproduzido" são coisas diferentes

Tags: debate, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Vejo muito o pessoal marcando uma pergunta que não tem como você saber qual o problema, ou o que ela deveria fazer, ou falta alguma informação relevante para conseguir reproduzir o problema, e principalmente porque esse último caso dispara um gatilho na pessoa ela fecha como `não pode ser reproduzido`.

O motivo `não pode ser reproduzido` existe para indicar que você testou o código e não aconteceu o que a pessoa diz acontecer. Quase sempre que faz isso, você deveria mostrar o teste que fez (que a pessoa que perguntou deveria ter feito, mas sabemos que o usuário típico do SOpt nunca faz, ele sempre terceiriza tudo para os outros, seja por preguiça, seja por desconhecimento do processo para se chegar em uma solução de forma adequada) e que se o AP tivesse feito um MVCE nem teria postado a pergunta.

Já parou para pensar porque ele está junto do `erro de digitação`? É porque a pergunta não tem serventia para ninguém, não tem como responder porque não tem um problema ali.

Quando **você** não consegue reproduzir porque você não tem todas informações necessárias a pergunta **não está clara** ou **deve ser melhorada**. É diferente de ninguém conseguir reproduzir porque não tem erro. Vote o motivo certo!

Escolha sempre o erro mais importante, mesmo quando possa ter sentido aquele motivo de fechamento.

Por isso que muita gente vota uma pergunta como `não está em português` quando tem um erro muito mais grave e por isso se a pergunta for traduzida [ela continua fechada porque o erro maior não foi consertado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108). Outro alerta para as pessoas pensar melhor na hora de fechar (achei interessante por esse jabuti pra aproveitar a instrução :) ).

### Versão curta:

- **Não pode ser reproduzido:** você comprovou que aquilo que o autor afirma não ocorre de fato
- **Não clara:** falta informação para aferir se o que o autor disse procede

Comment: Acredito que o autor desta proeza sou eu, bom, pelo menos lembro-me de uma pergunta especifica que votei que nem um trecho de código tem nela e que bate com o horário de seu feedback. Ficarei mais atento a questão.

Comment: As vezes eu tenho dúvida também entre o "não está clara" e o "Apesar de ser sobre programação, esta pergunta não parece atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento para um site de perguntas e respostas. As perguntas aqui precisam ser para problemas específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software. Melhore a pergunta.", creio que muitas vezes ambos estariam corretos.

Comment: @danieltakeshi nem sempre é fácil mesmo. Em geral o não clara é quando tem alguma informação mas falta outras. Quando falta quase tudo, ou principalmente a pessoa nem tentou fazer, então não é falta de clareza, ela quer que façamos pra ela. Em alguns casos pode ser usado quando tem problemas demais, é fortemente não clara, é ampla, é baseada em opinião. A pergunta não clara pode ser salva adicionando alguma informação que falta, a fora de escopo só salva se ela virar outra pergunta, passar ter um problema específico e não um pedido de ajuda genérico. Ajuda genérica é fora de escopo.Por isso...

Comment: Fica complicado agora algumas pessoas começarem pedir para o SOpt ser mais flexível porque cwegamos criar um motivo de fechamento só para evitar isso, agora não é mais para usar isso? Só porque alguém quer responder algo então devemos começar deixar? Mesmo que não produz uma resposta boa porque a pergunta não é boa? Isso é o que nos difere de fórum. Você não pode confiar muito em respostas em fóruns, porque pode sair qualquer coisa, fruto de voluntarismo. Aqui precisa sair algo bom e pra isso a pergunta tem que ser boa, tem que ter foco, tem que ser um problema bem definido.

Comment: Vou aproveitar para dizer que algo só é spam quando há clara intenção. Se a pessoa colocou ingenuamente algo que não tem motivação divulgar algo, é só tirar o *link*, não precisamos considerar *spam*. Mesmo em alguns casos pode passar se o *link* tiver relevância para a pergunta ou resposta, fica claro a relação, a pessoa demonstra não ter intenção de fazer publicidade e não terá ganhos.