# Qual motivo de fechamento escolher, caso mais de um seja aplicável?

Tags: suporte, fechamento

Gostaria de saber, qual motivo de fechamento devo priorizar para cada situação. Vamos testar este primeiro cenário, inspirado a partir [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/582237/error-in-reactjs-expected):

> I need some help with my Python code.
>
> `pint("hello world");`
>
> Can someone help me why it is not running?

Eu posso escolher para fechar essa pergunta:

- Essa pergunta não está em Português.
- É um erro de digitação.
- Não atende critérios de qualidade.

Agora vamos para essa, [inspirada nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/582228/estou-tentando-imprimir-um-qr-code-via-c-tcp-ip-na-impressora-tm-t20x-fa-epson):

> Estou tentando fazer X, já tentei de tudo...
>
> [um monte de código sem explicação]

Dentre as opções:

- Não atende critérios de qualidade.
- Precisa de detalhes ou esclarecimentos.

Dentre algumas outras situações que não precisam ser mencionadas.

Agora minha dúvida é: as vezes, vários motivos de fechamento se enquadram em uma postagem, mas não sei qual devo priorizar em certos casos.

Como posso aprender a escolher corretamente o motivo de fechamento de uma pergunta?

Comment: Na primeira hipótese, eu vejo como uma pergunta sobre um erro de digitação, mal elaborada(falta ainda título e tags para análise) que está em lingua estrangeira. Então fecharia como erro de digitação e deixaria um comentário para o AP informando o erro e a correção.

Comment: O problema @AugustoVasques, é que essa é a sua decisão, sua ação, e não algo coordenado por toda a comunidade. Gostaria de saber se existe um "guia" que deve ser seguido.

Comment: Para fechar, é necessário mais de um voto, cada um pode votar no motivo que preferir. O importante é fechar as perguntas ruins, independente do motivo. Pessoalmente, eu as vezes voto por motivo de não estar em português sem nem ler a pergunta, apenas por ser mais rápido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso de pergunta em inglês, já foi discutido [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7108/112052). Mas resumindo, basta pensar o seguinte: se a pergunta estivesse em português, ela deveria ficar aberta ou fechada? Se a resposta for "aberta", escolha o fechamento "não está em português", e caso ela seja traduzida, poderá ser reaberta. Se a resposta for "fechada", aí fecha-se com o motivo que seria escolhido se ela estivesse em português.

Já no caso de pergunta em português: se mais de um motivo se aplica, eu simplesmente escolho qualquer um. No meu entendimento, **tanto faz**, pois se a pergunta é tão fora do escopo que se encaixa em vários motivos de fechamento, então o mais importante é fechá-la logo. Meu raciocínio é que, se mais de um motivo é aplicável, então qualquer um que eu escolher estará correto.